# How to give html tags in javascript for Facebook.ui?

Tags: javascript, html, jspx

I am using a send method of the facebook ui,it consists of a description parameter where i am composing a particular message.I need to show one particular text to be in black,bold,normal font.

The code is like,
$('#send').click(function () 
                {

```
                                FB.ui({
                                    method: 'apprequests',
                                    message: "FaceBook Friends"
                                },Api); 

            });

            function Api(responses) 
            {      
                var eventName = document.getElementById("eventName").value;

                 var Message ="You have been invited for an event &lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;font color=\"black\"&gt;" + eventName +  "&lt;/           font&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt; " ;     //to give black font to eventName
                //var varMessage ='You have been invited for an event  <html><body><font color="black"><b>' +eventName+ '</b></font></body></html>' ;   

               FB.ui
                ({
                    method: 'send',
                    to: responses.to,
                    name: document.getElementById("eventName").value,
                    link : 'www.google.com', 
                        description: Message

                });
```

Now it is taking the html tags also as text.Is it possible to display so?
Your ideas are welcome.